# How to prove this equality?

Tags: boolean-algebra

I would like to prove the following using boolean algebra and not karnaugh maps but I'm stuck:

> CD' + CDAB' + C'D'AB' = CD' + CAB' + D'AB'

Comment: You can't be stuck because you can evaluate both sides at 16 points and check that they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

If $C \bar{D}$ then clearly both sides are equal,
so suppose $\overline{C \bar{D}} = \bar{C}+D $ is true.

If $\bar{C}+D$ is true then $\bar{C} \bar{D} + CD = (\bar{C}+D) (\bar{C} \bar{D} + CD )= \bar{C} \bar{D} + CD$ and
$C+ \bar{D} = (C+ \bar{D})(\bar{C}+D) = \bar{C} \bar{D} + CD$, hence
$A\bar{B} (\bar{C} \bar{D} + CD) = A\bar{B} (C+ \bar{D})$